# How to add event listeners to the numeric stepper's text box?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a numeric stepper and I want to add an event listener to its text box:

```
use namespace mx_internal;
durationStepper.inputField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,durationStepperTextInputChanged);

private function durationStepperTextInputChanged(event:Event):void
{ 
    use namespace mx_internal;
    trace(durationStepper.inputField.text);
}
```

However, the event function does not execute! I put a break point there and it does not reach it! What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please write which real scenario you would like to implement? Is it not enough to use the Change Event of the Stepper itself?

Comment: Well, I need to detect when the user deletes the contents of the numeric stepper completely. The default behavior of the component in this case is to return to its minimum value, but I have to set it to some default value. The problem is that I have no way to distinguish between when the minimum value is set as a result of clearing the contents and when the user purposely set it, so I thought of using the input field to detect changes and check if its text is empty.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have checked this behavior in my code, it works fine.

Comment: Did you get it to work? Can you please explain me how?

Comment: I have described it in my answer. Have you tried it? You should change the source code of the stepper.

Comment: You can download the solution from the link given at the end of my answer. I hope it will help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the developer has stopped Change event from bubbling up. You can find it if you go to the source file of the NumericStepper. Here are two functions, which prevent you from getting the event.

```
override protected function createChildren():void
{
    super.createChildren();

    if (!inputField)
    {
        inputField = new TextInput();

        //some code

        //some code

        inputField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, inputField_changeHandler);

        addChild(inputField);
    }
}

private function inputField_changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // Stop the event from bubbling up.
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var inputValue:Number = Number(inputField.text);
    if ((inputValue != value &&
        (Math.abs(inputValue - value) >= 0.000001 || isNaN(inputValue))) || 
        inputField.text == "")
    {
        _value = checkValidValue(inputValue);
    }
}
```

As you can see the second function has 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

In this case you have two options: either you should find another way of implementing your logic, or you can copy the source code of the component and eliminate this code line.

It would be fine to override the function, but it is private.

You can read about this common problem [here](http://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2007/03/08/private-functions-in-flex-source-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)

I have tried to choose the second way. It works perfectly! It is not only the *.as file, but some others, which are used in it.

You can download the component [here](http://it-skills.su/ifolder/com.zip).